# mysql cli: how to list all databases I have permisions to create/read/update/delete?

Tags: mysql, database, command-line-interface

What command do I use on a mysql command line to see all the databases on some database server that I have permissions to? Specifically I am looking for the DBs that I have full CRUD permissions to.

Comment: @Thr4wn see my edit.  I gave you another query to try based on the specific permissions you want to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysql -e "show databases"

---

**UPDATE**:

Based on your edit, here is a query you can run against the `mysql` database in your server:

```
mysql> select Db from db where User='aj' and (select_priv='Y' and insert_priv='Y' and update_priv='Y' and delete_priv='Y');
+---------+
| Db      |
+---------+
| HopeDB  |
| LocusDB |
+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```